# How to use subquery in LIKE statement in Impala?

Tags: hadoop, impala

I have a lookup table that contains forbidden values/strings and a rule number which depicts where the value cannot occur. So for e.g., I have ‘C/O’ as a value and this can’t occur anywhere in a name field. I also have ‘P.O’ which can’t occur in an address. I am attempting to create a data quality report to flag these values without hard coding. I have tried:

```
Select 
A.name
,A.address
From customer A
Where a.name LIKE (Select concat(‘%’, exclusion_value, ‘%’) from DQ_lookup where rule_number=2)
Or a.address LIKE (Select concat(‘%’, exclusion_value, ‘%’) from DQ_lookup where rule_number=1)
```

This fails. How if at all can I get this to work ?

Comment: Yeah `LIKE` requires strings as arguments, https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_operators.html#like, while `SELECT` has potential to return a cursor. What if you try to use something like `MAX()` in your subselect, `...WHERE a.name LIKE (Select MAX(concat(‘%’, exclusion_value, ‘%’)) from ...`?

Comment: Thanks so much I will go take a look at this now

Comment: Very well, thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For matching patterns in hive, you would need to use `rlike`.

> [A RLIKE B](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)
> : NULL if A or B is NULL, TRUE if any (possibly empty) substring of A matches the Java regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. For example, 'foobar' RLIKE 'foo' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' RLIKE '^f.*r$'.

Something as below would do.

```
Select 
 A.name,
 A.address
From customer A
Where 
 a.name RLIKE (Select exclusion_value from DQ_lookup where rule_number=2)
 OR a.address RLIKE (Select exclusion_value from DQ_lookup where rule_number=1)
```

*Note: exclusion_value should be a regex expression.*